# Multiple renaming using ant script

Tags: ant

Let me explain the scenario:

```
D:\project\src\one.txt
D:\project\src\two.txt
D:\project\src\three.txt
D:\project\src\four.txt
```

The above files should be copied as :

```
D:\project\dst\one.xls
D:\project\dst\two.xls
D:\project\dst\three.xls
D:\project\dst\four.xls
```

I need to change the extension without using the mapper and move task. I need to rename as above using a for loop with `fte:filecopy` function inside. Is this possible ???

Comment: Why can't you use a mapper with a copy or move task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone arriving here without the negative requirement afflicting the OP, the much simpler answer is to use a mapper.

```
<project default="move_files">
  <target name="move_files">
    <copy todir="dst">
      <fileset dir="src">
        <include name="*.txt"/>
      </fileset>
      <globmapper from="*.txt" to="*.xls"/>
    </copy>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="so-copy-rename" default="build2">

    <property name="ant-contrib-jar" value="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>

    <target name="setup" unless="ant-contrib.present">
        <echo>Getting ant-contrib</echo>
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <!--
            Note: change this to a locally hosted maven repository manager such as nexus http://nexus.sonatype.org/
        -->
        <get dest="${ant-contrib-jar}"
             src="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>  
    </target>

    <target name="taskdefs">
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${ant-contrib-jar}"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="taskdefs">

        <property name="srcdir" value="src"/>
        <property name="targetdir" value="target"/>
        <property name="files" value="file1,file2,file3,file4"/>

        <mkdir dir="${targetdir}"/>

        <foreach list="${files}" target="copy-rename" param="srcfile" trim="true">

            <param name="srcdir" value="${srcdir}" />
            <param name="targetdir" value="${targetdir}" />

        </foreach>

    </target>

    <target name="copy-rename">

        <var name="src-suffix" value="txt"/>
        <var name="tgt-suffix" value="xls"/>

        <copy file="${srcdir}/${srcfile}.${src-suffix}" tofile="${targetdir}/${srcfile}.${tgt-suffix}" />

    </target>

<target name="build2" depends="taskdefs">

    <property name="srcdir" value="src"/>
    <property name="targetdir" value="target"/>

    <mkdir dir="${targetdir}"/>

    <foreach target="copy-rename2" param="srcfile">
        <path id="srcfilepath">
            <fileset dir="${srcdir}" casesensitive="yes">
                <include name="*.txt"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>

        <param name="targetdir" value="${targetdir}" />
    </foreach>


</target>

<target name="copy-rename2">

    <var name="basefile" value="" unset="true"/>
    <basename property="basefile" file="${srcfile}" suffix=".txt"/>

    <var name="tgt-suffix" value="xls"/>

    <copy file="${srcfile}" tofile="${targetdir}/${basefile}.${tgt-suffix}" />

</target>

</project>
```

Comment: Hi Crowne this will work if we specify the name of the four files as file1,file2,file3,file4. But what if i have a thousand .txt files. Is there any way to capture the Localfilebase alone i.e (if the filename is hello.txt, i need to extract hello alone)

Comment: The ant task "basename" does exactly that. I've added 2 targets in the script above build2 and copy-rename2 using filesets and basename.

Answer (score 0):

Can you slice it the other way and perform the renaming inside the `fte:filecopy` command? Looking at [the IBM documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/file_copy.htm), you can specify tasks to be carried out at the source or destination agents either before or after the copy, using `presrc`, `postdst` etc. This [task](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/nested_params.htm) could be an Ant task that does the renaming?